# Watch multiple attributes not working Angular js

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to auto-populate date field based on the combination of two fields on my page.
The main page is `Institution`, in this main page I have a sub section for employees. I want to watch 2 fields in sub section, I tried this code but it is not working.

```
      $scope.$watch(function () { return vm.institution.employees.length }, function () {
        _.forEach(vm.institution.employees, function (item, index) {
            $scope.$watch(vm.institution.employees[index].occupation,vm.institution.employees[index].salary, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue[0] != oldValue[0]) {
                    vm.xx = 'test';
                }
            },true);

        });
    });
```

In this same institutions page employees sub section I am watching single attribute using below code it is working properly, but watching 2 is not working.

```
    $scope.$watch(function () { return vm.institution.employees.length }, function () {
        _.forEach(vm.institution.employees, function (item, index) {
            debugger;
            item.employeeDesignation = _.filter(vm.desginations, { id: item.designationTypeId });
            $scope.$watch(function () { return vm.institution.employees[index].designationTypeId }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue != oldValue) {
                    item.employeeDesignation = _.filter(vm.desginations, { id: newvalue });
                           }
            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can watch an array of expressions using $watchGroup. But in your case you can just watch vm.institution.employees and move additional logic to the callback.

```
$scope.$watch('vm.institution.employees', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue.occupation != oldValue.occupation || newValue.salary != oldValue.salary) {
    vm.xx = 'test';
  }
});
```

Comment: not working, date value should change whenever i change occupation or salary for existed/new employees. institutions--> employees relationship is one to many and i have add employee button in my institution page, can you please check my working code for single attribute,  am i missing any syntax in code for watching 2?